# Better Slider Control in Windows 8 Media App

Tags: c#, windows-8, controls

I'm developing Windows 8 App, it's use media element to play video and music
Windows 8 build in slider control is ugly and difficult to use on touch screen

I want something like this:
[Very beautiful slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVfQy.png)

Sorry, i don't have enough reputation to post images

How can I do this? Or what's the name of that control? I try transport slider, as show up here: [Designing great entertainment app for Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868270.aspx), but no luck

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That slider is available in [Player Framework](http://playerframework.codeplex.com/), an open source component of the Microsoft Media Platform.